# How to setup: tor traffic routing with a vpn and proxy for this purpose/ firewall that machine/ provide other privacy/ anonymity settings?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, proxy, tor

My goal, for the moment, is to setup a fresh home server using ubuntu 16.04.01 Desktop x64 where a VPN is to be created that would route all traffic from that specific server through the tor network. Not the Ubuntu server - if for any reason, professionals from this community consider this erroneous please expand, argument and I will learn and understand why.

1. Create a tor VPN with proxies for the added security;
2. Use only one web browser on that machine (perhaps a customized firefox that has all tor and security functionalities customized, no javascript, webrtc, etc);
3. Install and setup a firewall and fortify that machine accordingly;
4. Automatically change mac and other identifiers for the added layer of security;
5. Still be able to remotely connect (not necessarily only through ssh) to that machine for administrative and management purposes;

I have found that, information contained in certain youtube tutorials and specific Q&A sources/ forums do not necessarily contain updated and relevant information. Perhaps because they are either subjective or prefer certain types of tools or methodologies. Because of this I have, in numerous times, either broke my machine or used irrelevant and/or obsolete solutions and software.